# Pack header and data layout in one byte array using ByteBuffer in an efficient way?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, thread-safety, bytebuffer

I have a header and data which I need to represent in one `Byte Array`. And I have a particular format for packing the header in a `Byte Array` and also a different format to pack the data in a `Byte Array`. After I have these two, I need to make one final `Byte Array` out of it.

Below is the layout which is how defined in `C++` and accordingly I have to do in `Java`.

```
// below is my header offsets layout

// addressedCenter must be the first byte
static constexpr uint32_t  addressedCenter      = 0;
static constexpr uint32_t  version              = addressedCenter + 1;
static constexpr uint32_t  numberOfRecords      = version + 1;
static constexpr uint32_t  bufferUsed           = numberOfRecords + sizeof(uint32_t);
static constexpr uint32_t  location             = bufferUsed + sizeof(uint32_t);
static constexpr uint32_t  locationFrom         = location + sizeof(CustomerAddress);
static constexpr uint32_t  locationOrigin       = locationFrom + sizeof(CustomerAddress);
static constexpr uint32_t  partition            = locationOrigin + sizeof(CustomerAddress);
static constexpr uint32_t  copy                 = partition + 1;

// this is the full size of the header
static constexpr uint32_t headerOffset = copy + 1;
```

And `CustomerAddress` is a typedef for `uint64_t` and it is made up like this -

```
typedef uint64_t   CustomerAddress;

void client_data(uint8_t datacenter, 
                 uint16_t clientId, 
                 uint8_t dataId, 
                 uint32_t dataCounter,
                 CustomerAddress& customerAddress)
{
    customerAddress = (uint64_t(datacenter) << 56)
                    + (uint64_t(clientId) << 40)
                    + (uint64_t(dataId) << 32)
                    + dataCounter;
}
```

And below is my data layout -

```
// below is my data layout -
//
// key type - 1 byte
// key len - 1 byte
// key (variable size = key_len)
// timestamp (sizeof uint64_t)
// data size (sizeof uint16_t)
// data (variable size = data size)
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Now for a part of project, I am trying to represent overall stuff in one particular class in Java so that I can just pass the necessary fields and it can make me a final `Byte Array` out of it which will have the header first and then the data:

Below is my `DataFrame` class:

```
public final class DataFrame {
  private final byte addressedCenter;
  private final byte version;
  private final Map<byte[], byte[]> keyDataHolder;
  private final long location;
  private final long locationFrom;
  private final long locationOrigin;
  private final byte partition;
  private final byte copy;

  public DataFrame(byte addressedCenter, byte version,
      Map<byte[], byte[]> keyDataHolder, long location, long locationFrom,
      long locationOrigin, byte partition, byte copy) {
    this.addressedCenter = addressedCenter;
    this.version = version;
    this.keyDataHolder = keyDataHolder;
    this.location = location;
    this.locationFrom = locationFrom;
    this.locationOrigin = locationOrigin;
    this.partition = partition;
    this.copy = copy;
  }

  public byte[] serialize() {
    // All of the data is embedded in a binary array with fixed maximum size 70000
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(70000);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);

    int numOfRecords = keyDataHolder.size();
    int bufferUsed = getBufferUsed(keyDataHolder); // 36 + dataSize + 1 + 1 + keyLength + 8 + 2;

    // header layout
    byteBuffer.put(addressedCenter); // byte
    byteBuffer.put(version); // byte
    byteBuffer.putInt(numOfRecords); // int
    byteBuffer.putInt(bufferUsed); // int
    byteBuffer.putLong(location); // long
    byteBuffer.putLong(locationFrom); // long
    byteBuffer.putLong(locationOrigin); // long
    byteBuffer.put(partition); // byte
    byteBuffer.put(copy); // byte

    // now the data layout
    for (Map.Entry<byte[], byte[]> entry : keyDataHolder.entrySet()) {
      byte keyType = 0;
      byte keyLength = (byte) entry.getKey().length;
      byte[] key = entry.getKey();
      byte[] data = entry.getValue();
      short dataSize = (short) data.length;

      ByteBuffer dataBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
      long timestamp = 0;

      if (dataSize > 10) {
        timestamp = dataBuffer.getLong(2);              
      }       

      byteBuffer.put(keyType);
      byteBuffer.put(keyLength);
      byteBuffer.put(key);
      byteBuffer.putLong(timestamp);
      byteBuffer.putShort(dataSize);
      byteBuffer.put(data);
    }
    return byteBuffer.array();
  }

  private int getBufferUsed(final Map<byte[], byte[]> keyDataHolder) {
    int size = 36;
    for (Map.Entry<byte[], byte[]> entry : keyDataHolder.entrySet()) {
      size += 1 + 1 + 8 + 2;
      size += entry.getKey().length;
      size += entry.getValue().length;
    }
    return size;
  }  
}
```

And below is how I am using my above `DataFrame` class:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // header layout
    byte addressedCenter = 0;
    byte version = 1;

    long location = packCustomerAddress((byte) 12, (short) 13, (byte) 32, (int) 120);
    long locationFrom = packCustomerAddress((byte) 21, (short) 23, (byte) 41, (int) 130);
    long locationOrigin = packCustomerAddress((byte) 21, (short) 24, (byte) 41, (int) 140);

    byte partition = 3;
    byte copy = 0;

    // this map will have key as the actual key and value as the actual data, both in byte array
    // for now I am storing only two entries in this map
    Map<byte[], byte[]> keyDataHolder = new HashMap<byte[], byte[]>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
      keyDataHolder.put(generateKey(), getMyData());
    }

    DataFrame records =
        new DataFrame(addressedCenter, version, keyDataHolder, location, locationFrom,
            locationOrigin, partition, copy);

    // this will give me final packed byte array
    // which will have header and data in it.
    byte[] packedArray = records.serialize();
  }

  private static long packCustomerAddress(byte datacenter, short clientId, byte dataId,
      int dataCounter) {
    return ((long) (datacenter) << 56) | ((long) clientId << 40) | ((long) dataId << 32)
        | ((long) dataCounter);
  }
```

As you can see in my `DataFrame` class, I am allocating `ByteBuffer` with predefined size of `70000`. Is there a better way by which I can allocate the size I am using while making `ByteBuffer` instead of using a hardcoded `70000`?

Also is there any better way as compared to what I am doing which packs my header and data in one byte array? I also need to make sure it is thread safe since it can be called by multiple threads.

Comment: The byteBuffer should not be static in a multi-threaded context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way by which I can allocate the size I am using while making `ByteBuffer` instead of using a hardcoded `70000`?

There are at least two, non-overlapping approaches.  You may use both.

One is buffer pooling.  You should find out how many buffers you need during peak periods, and use a maximum above it, e.g. max + max / 2, max + average, max + mode, 2 * max.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class ByteBufferPool {
    private final int bufferCapacity;
    private final LinkedBlockingDeque<ByteBuffer> queue;

    public ByteBufferPool(int limit, int bufferCapacity) {
        if (limit < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("limit must not be negative.");
        if (bufferCapacity < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("bufferCapacity must not be negative.");

        this.bufferCapacity = bufferCapacity;
        this.queue = (limit == 0) ? null : new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(limit);
    }

    public ByteBuffer acquire() {
        ByteBuffer buffer = (queue == null) ? null : queue.pollFirst();
        if (buffer == null) {
            buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferCapacity);
        }
        else {
            buffer.clear();
            buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        }
        return buffer;
    }

    public boolean release(ByteBuffer buffer) {
        if (buffer == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("buffer must not be null.");
        if (buffer.capacity() != bufferCapacity) throw new IllegalArgumentException("buffer has unsupported capacity.");
        if (buffer.isDirect()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("buffer must not be direct.");
        if (buffer.isReadOnly()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("buffer must not be read-only.");

        return (queue == null) ? false : queue.offerFirst(buffer);
    }

    public void withBuffer(Consumer<ByteBuffer> action) {
        if (action == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("action must not be null.");

        ByteBuffer buffer = acquire();
        try {
            action.accept(buffer);
        }
        finally {
            release(buffer);
        }
    }

    public <T> T withBuffer(Function<ByteBuffer, T> function) {
        if (function == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("function must not be null.");

        ByteBuffer buffer = acquire();
        try {
            return function.apply(buffer);
        }
        finally {
            release(buffer);
        }
    }

    public <T> CompletionStage<T> withBufferAsync(Function<ByteBuffer, CompletionStage<T>> asyncFunction) {
        if (asyncFunction == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("asyncFunction must not be null.");

        ByteBuffer buffer = acquire();
        CompletionStage<T> future = null;
        try {
            future = asyncFunction.apply(buffer);
        }
        finally {
            if (future == null) {
                release(buffer);
            }
            else {
                future = future.whenComplete((result, throwable) -> release(buffer));
            }
        }
        return future;
    }
}
```

The `withBuffer` methods allow a straight forward usage of the pool, while the `acquire` and `release` allow separating the acquisition and releasing points.

Another one is segregating the serialization interface, e.g. the `put`, `putInt` and `putLong`, where you can then implement a byte counting class and an actual byte buffering class.  You should add a method to such interface to know if the serializer is counting bytes or buffering, in order to avoid unnecessary byte generation, and another method to increment byte usage directly, useful when calculating the size of a string in some encoding without actually serializing.

```
public interface ByteSerializer {
    ByteSerializer put(byte value);

    ByteSerializer putInt(int value);

    ByteSerializer putLong(long value);

    boolean isSerializing();

    ByteSerializer add(int bytes);

    int position();
}
```

```
public class ByteCountSerializer implements ByteSerializer {
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public ByteSerializer put(byte value) {
        count += 1;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ByteSerializer putInt(int value) {
        count += 4;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ByteSerializer putLong(long value) {
        count += 8;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSerializing() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public ByteSerializer add(int bytes) {
        if (bytes < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("bytes must not be negative.");

        count += bytes;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public int position() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class ByteBufferSerializer implements ByteSerializer {
    private final ByteBuffer buffer;

    public ByteBufferSerializer(int bufferCapacity) {
        if (bufferCapacity < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("bufferCapacity must not be negative.");

        this.buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferCapacity);
    }

    @Override
    public ByteSerializer put(byte value) {
        buffer.put(value);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ByteSerializer putInt(int value) {
        buffer.putInt(value);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ByteSerializer putLong(long value) {
        buffer.putLong(value);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSerializing() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public ByteSerializer add(int bytes) {
        if (bytes < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("bytes must not be negative.");

        for (int b = 0; b < bytes; b++) {
            buffer.put((byte)0);
        }
        return this;
        // or throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public int position() {
        return buffer.position();
    }

    public ByteBuffer buffer() {
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

In your code, you'd do something along these lines (not tested):

```
ByteCountSerializer counter = new ByteCountSerializer();
dataFrame.serialize(counter);
ByteBufferSerializer serializer = new ByteByfferSerializer(counter.position());
dataFrame.serialize(serializer);
ByteBuffer buffer = serializer.buffer();
// ... write buffer, ?, profit ...
```

Your `DataFrame.serialize` method should be refactored to accept a `ByteSerializer`, and in cases where it would generate data, it should check `isSerializing` to know if it should only calculate the size or actually write bytes.

I leave combining both approaches as an exercise, mainly because it depends a lot on how you decide to do it.

For instance, you may make `ByteBufferSerializer` use the pool directly and keep an arbitrary capacity (e.g. your 70000), you may pool `ByteBuffer`s by capacity (but instead of the needed capacity, use the least power of 2 greater than the needed capacity, and set the buffer's limit before returning from `acquire`), or you may pool `ByteBufferSerializer`s directly as long as you add a `reset()` method.

> Also is there any better way as compared to what I am doing which packs my header and data in one byte array?

Yes.  Pass around the byte buffering instance instead of having certain methods return byte arrays which are discarded the moment after their length is checked or their contents are copied.

> I also need to make sure it is thread safe since it can be called by multiple threads.

As long as each buffer is being used by only one thread, with proper synchronization, you don't have to worry.

Proper synchronization means your pool manager has acquire and release semantics in its methods, and that if a buffer is used by multiple threads between fetching it from and returning it to the pool, you are adding release semantics in the thread that stops using the buffer and adding acquire semantics in the thread that starts using the buffer.  For instance, if you're passing the buffer through `CompletableFuture`s, you shouldn't have to worry about this, or if you're communicating explicitly between threads with an `Exchanger` or a proper implementation of `BlockingQueue`.

From `java.util.concurrent`'s package description:

> The methods of all classes in `java.util.concurrent` and its subpackages extend these guarantees to higher-level synchronization. In particular:
>
> - Actions in a thread prior to placing an object into any concurrent collection *happen-before* actions subsequent to the access or removal of that element from the collection in another thread.
> - Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a `Runnable` to an `Executor` *happen-before* its execution begins. Similarly for `Callables` submitted to an `ExecutorService`.
> - Actions taken by the asynchronous computation represented by a `Future` *happen-before* actions subsequent to the retrieval of the result via `Future.get()` in another thread.
> - Actions prior to "releasing" synchronizer methods such as `Lock.unlock`, `Semaphore.release`, and `CountDownLatch.countDown` *happen-before* actions subsequent to a successful "acquiring" method such as `Lock.lock`, `Semaphore.acquire`, `Condition.await`, and `CountDownLatch.await` on the same synchronizer object in another thread.
> - For each pair of threads that successfully exchange objects via an `Exchanger`, actions prior to the `exchange()` in each thread *happen-before* those subsequent to the corresponding `exchange()` in another thread.
> - Actions prior to calling `CyclicBarrier.await` and `Phaser.awaitAdvance` (as well as its variants) *happen-before* actions performed by the barrier action, and actions performed by the barrier action *happen-before* actions subsequent to a successful return from the corresponding `await` in other threads.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you provide me an example for the first two suggestion in your answer so that I can understand better? Right now I am confuse how does this will work.

Comment: Ok, I added the examples.

Comment: I will be very honest.. I was able to grasp some part from your examples. But I am not able to understand how I will use your suggestion in my code. You mentioned you are leaving this as an exercise for me and I am afraid I am not sure how I will integrate with mine.. I have always work with very low level API's of bytebuffer and dealing with bytes so pardon my ignorance on this. I have to learn all these things looks like. If you can help me provide an example how will this gets integrated with mine then it will be of great help.

Comment: I left as an *exercise* the part where you would do both pooling and a counting-only serializer.  Although most high performance server code ends up pooling buffers, I recommend you to profile and gather any evidence that your buffers are not short lived, because if they are, then the GC will do a good job getting rid of them from the youngest generation(s) and pooling means overhead.

Comment: And in all honesty, if even after the examples you still only understand a part and you can't see how to integrate in your code, you seriously need Java training.  The examples are very basic, straight to the subject and mostly boilerplate, more so if you use `LinkedBlockingDeque` instead of `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` to get rid of the `limit` and `count` fields, since `LinkedBlockingDeque` can have a limit and `LinkedBlockingDeque.size()` is O(1).

Comment: These basic datastructures I know very well but the part I am confuse is how this will get integrated in the current code I have. Currently I take parameters in the constructor and constructor ByteBuffer by calling its individual methods and I am not able to understand how we can do this in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it would be via a `DataOutputStream` around a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, but you should concentrate your performance tuning around the places it's needed, and this isn't one of them. Efficiency isn't any kind of an issue here. The network I/O will dominate by orders of magnitude.

Another reason to use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` is that you don't have to guess the buffer size in advance: it will grow as necessary.

To keep it thread-safe, use only local variables.

Comment: Even if the network I/O is less efficient by orders of magnitude, what if you're implementing a server that must handle millions of simultaneously active connections?  Buffer allocation (and copying) is one of the culprits of performance in such servers implemented in Java and .NET.

Comment: @acelent Then you need a lot of CPU power. But there's nothing particularly inefficient about the OP's code except the pre-allocation of 7000 bytes.